# Deploy app onto a real device and get rid of local-dev-server dependence

Tags: react-native

Appreciate your lecture.

Currently, I can successfully deploy the app onto my iPhone device.

However, the app is rely on local-dev-server.

How could I get rid of the local-dev-server?

I used this command to deploy the app  `react-native run-ios --device 'iPhone'` onto my cellphone

Here's my repo

https://github.com/poc7667/reacti-native-album

Answer (score 0):

Here is a section from RN docs:

Building an app for distribution in the App Store requires using the Release scheme in Xcode. Apps built for Release will automatically disable the in-app Developer menu, which will prevent your users from inadvertently accessing the menu in production. It will also bundle the JavaScript locally, so you can put the app on a device and test whilst not connected to the computer.

To configure your app to be built using the Release scheme, go to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme. Select the Run tab in the sidebar, then set the Build Configuration dropdown to Release.

[image]

> you just need to select the `Release` scheme on the run configuration in xCode and hit the run button.